# Get user detail from rstudio connect published shiny app into app.R code

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio-connect

**Problem Statement:** I have a shiny app hosted on Rstudio Connect. In this I want specific information to be show to users based on their roles. For which I need the details of the user from Rstudio-connect to my app.R code when they log into application. So I can compare that with role based data and display relevant information.

*I need help in getting user details from rstudio-connect to my shiny code.*

Any leads can be helpful!

Comment: If you have an account, have you asked their support on how to do this?

Comment: am3010, if I'm off-the-mark and that does not work for you, comment and @ping me and we'll discuss.